# Angular service not available

Tags: angularjs, service, module

I get that error in angular:

```
Module 'SecurityResource' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Here is the code for it (all of it)

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

function SecurityResource($resource){
  return $resource('/authenticate', {email: userName, password: password}, {
    login: {
      method: 'POST'
    }
  });
}

angular.module('Security',[])
    .factory('SecurityResource', SecurityResource);

})();
```

in combination with

```
    (function(){
  'use strict';

function SecurityService(SecurityResource){
  var security = {};

  return {
      login: function(userName, password){
        SecurityResource.login({email: userName, password: password}, function(response){
            if(response){
              security.User = response.user;
              security.BusinessUnits = response.businessUnits;
            }
        });
      }
  };
}

angular.module('Security', ['SecurityResource'])
  .factory('SecurityService', SecurityService);
})();
```

and I include it in index.html

and it is injected in the login directive like this

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', ['Security'])
        .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

    LoginController.$inject = ['$location', 'FlashService', 'SecurityService'];
    function LoginController($location, FlashService, SecurityService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.login = login;

        function login() {
            vm.dataLoading = true;
            SecurityService.login(vm.username, vm.password);
            $location.path('/');

    }
})();
```

Can anyone see what it wrong in here? It looks like I'm not calling it properly.

Comment: Help! I've been stuck with this for days, really can't see what's wrong!

Comment: tried reorganising all the files in index.html... no change